# How to get current payment detail on order review page in Magento 1.9.2?

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

I want to print complete payment details on order review page in onepage checkout which are saved while payment. I have used following code:-

```
<?php echo$payment = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle(); ?>
```

But This code is getting only Payment title but I want to print following details:-

- Card holder name:-
- Expire date:-
- Card No:-
- Card Type:-

Answer (score 0):

Use `print_r(getQuote()->getPayment()->debug())` to see what other values are available, or view the `sales_flat_order_payment` table to see some more examples.

```
$cards = $payment->getMethodInstance()->getCardsStorage()->getCards();
```

In array $cards y have those datasets;

Comment: I have tried but could't work. When we proceeding to Next step after filling payments details it is automatically redirecting on cart page

Comment: Could you please suggest me another code?

Comment: What contains array `$cards` ?  make `var_dump($cards)`;